# JList Moving Lists Program

Tags: java, swing, compiler-warnings, jlist

I don't know where I'm going wrong but here's my code and I'm facing this error.
Basically I was watching Bucky Roberts' Tutorial on moving lists program and I'm stumbling over this error.

```
Note: .\Multiple_Selection_List.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Multiple_Selection_List extends JFrame
{
    private JList leftList;
    private JList rightList;
    private JButton moveButton;
    private DefaultListModel model;
    private DefaultListModel model2;

    public Multiple_Selection_List()
    {
        super("Multiple Selection List");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        model=new DefaultListModel();
        model.addElement("Random");

        model2 = new DefaultListModel();
        model2.addElement("Random");

        leftList = new JList(model);
        leftList.setVisibleRowCount(3);
        leftList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        add(new JScrollPane(leftList));

        moveButton = new JButton("Move to right  ------------->");
        moveButton.addActionListener
        (
            new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    rightList.setListData(leftList.getSelectedValuesList().toArray());
                }
            }
        );

        add(moveButton);

        rightList=new JList(model2);
        rightList.setVisibleRowCount(3);
        rightList.setFixedCellWidth(100);
        rightList.setFixedCellHeight(15);
        rightList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        add(new JScrollPane(rightList));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually a warning and not an error, so you should still be able to run it.  Have you compiled with this flag and gotten further details?

Comment: I don,t actually know how to compile it further.. Do you mind if you could help me with that?

Comment: `javac -Xlint:unchecked Multiple_Selection_List.java`

Answer (score 1):

Since generics were added into Java back in JDK5 (I think) you should specify the class of the object that you want to add to the JList. Then the compiler can verify that you add the appropriate data to the JList.

You specify code with generics like:

```
model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
model.addElement("Random");
leftList = new JList<String>( model );
```

Now the compiler will verify you actually add a String object to the model and a model object containing strings to the JList.

Of course you also specify the class when you define the model and list variables.